# How to use Room Relation annotations to JOIN several objects at once?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

Recently learned about such a thing as Relation annotation in Room, but immediately came to a dead end from misunderstanding. I have the following database model:

**DatabaseCategory**

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class DatabaseCategory(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int = 0,
    val name: String ="",
    val description: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "picture_url") val pictureUrl: String = "",
)
```

**DatabaseProduct**

```
@Entity(tableName = "products",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = DatabaseCategory::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("category_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["category_id"])]
)
data class DatabaseProduct(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val name: String,
    val price: Float,
    val discount: Float = 0f,
    val description: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id") val categoryId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "picture_url") val pictureUrl: String,
    val recent: OffsetDateTime? = null
)
```

**DatabaseCartItem**

```
@Entity(tableName = "cart",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = DatabaseProduct::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("product_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["product_id"])])
data class DatabaseCartItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    val productId: Long,
    var quantity: Int = 0
)
```

I figured out how to use this tool in the simplest case.

```
data class DatabaseCategoryWithProducts(
    @Embedded val category: DatabaseCategory,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "category_id"
    )
    val products: List<DatabaseProduct>
)
```

The question is: how to specify an object for Room and DAO query so that I can get such an object

```
data class DomainCartItem(
    val id: Long,
    val product: Product,
    val category: Category,
    val quantity: Int
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want try next object:

```
data class DomainCartItem(
    @Embedded val product: DatabaseProduct, // <-- here you get your id and quantity
    
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "category_id",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val category:DatabaseCategory,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "productId"
    )
    val cartItem:DatabaseCartItem,
)
```

and dao method:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM products")
fun getDomainCartItems(): List<DomainCartItem>
```

**UPDATE**

To get only products that are contained as CartItems you can use another query:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM products JOIN cart on products.id = cart.productId")
fun getDomainCartItems(): List<DomainCartItem>
```

Comment: this the error i get: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter cartItem`

Comment: It seems you have products that are not contained in `CartItem`. Then you can make the `DomainCartItem`'s field nullable: `val cartItem:DatabaseCartItem?`

Comment: Updated answer with query for only products that are present in cart items

Comment: everything worked out. One thing: I had to change the name of the id field in DB for cartItem, because when I executed the sql query, it overlapped product id, so I got null even with your changed query.